# Why is my screen not rendering anything?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code. When I run this I am getting a blank screen. This block of code is inside `sceneDidLoad()` so they will get executed but not displaying anything. Am I missing something ?

```
let worldNode = SKNode()

let height = 100
let width = 100
let regions:[Float: String] = [-0.04: "sand", -0.08: "water", 0.9: "grass"]

let noiseSource = GKPerlinNoiseSource()
let noise: GKNoise = GKNoise(noiseSource: noiseSource)
let noiseMap: GKNoiseMap = GKNoiseMap(noise: noise)

let tileMapNode = SKTileMapNode()
tileMapNode.enableAutomapping = true
tileMapNode.numberOfRows = height
tileMapNode.numberOfColumns = width
worldNode.addChild(tileMapNode)

for y in 0 ... height {
    for x in 0 ... width {
        let currentHeight = noiseMap.value(atPosition: vector2(Int32(x), Int32(y)));

        for (key, value) in regions {
            if (currentHeight <= key) {
                //colourMap [y * mapChunkSize + x] = regions[i];
                let tileSize = CGSize(width: 32.0, height: 32.0)
                let tileTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: value)
                let tileDef = SKTileDefinition(texture: tileTexture, size: tileSize)
                let tileGroup = SKTileGroup(tileDefinition: tileDef)

                tileMapNode.setTileGroup(tileGroup, forColumn: x, row: y)

                print("Tiling: \(value)")
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

self.addChild(worldNode)
```

Comment: Are you adding worldNode to the scene anywhere?

Comment: @JamesP Updated my question. yes I am adding it just after the `for` loops. thanks :)

Comment: do you ever present the scene from the view

Comment: @Knight0fDragon If I add a `SKSpriteNode` to `worldNode` it works just fine. It is just this `SKTileMapNode` having issues with.

Comment: Why not use didMoveToView() ?

Comment: @Jack I am using GameplayKit integration..